# is it a bad practice to have a static field?

Tags: static, code-first

I use a static field in this situation because I think it is time consuming to recreate the object at each request.

```
private static AnalysedCompanies db = new AnalysedCompanies();

 public class AnalysedCompanies:DbContext
    {
...    

    }
```

I use Entity Framework code first.

than I have methods for saving and loading data from the database trough the db object. 
Is the static db object going to cause a bottleneck? Is this the right thing to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a ASP.net Web Application, static are shared by all users, so yes, that's pretty bad as it means that User A can possibly see/modify data that User B sees and leads to all sorts of headaches.

Static fields are fine for static data, that is data that a) is shared for everyone and b) isn't modified by users (as changes are global to all other users). I do use statics for stuff like System Configuration or objects that can be safely shared.

I think the main problem is this: "I think it is time consuming" - don't guess, measure. There are many profilers available for .net. If you have performance issues, measure to see if it really is a problem and then act.